# Find the standard matrix of T given T is a linear transformation

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

$T:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ first performs a horizontal sheer that transforms $e_2$ into $e_2 + 2e_1$ (leaving $e_1$ unchanged) and then reflects points through the line $x_2 = -x_1.$

I am unsure where to start with this, so could anyone explain to me how to solve this? Thanks!

For reference $e_1 $and $e_2$ are vectors, however since I am new to this I did not know how to format it in proper vector notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it one transformation at a time and then form the product of the matrices. So, to begin with, we have

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
=  \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

and by implication

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
=  \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

From this you should be able to work out what a, b, c and d are. Then, do the same thing for the next matrix. All you have to do then is multiply the matrices together. Just remember to put the first one on the right and the second on the left, to get them applying to the vector in the right order.

There's actually a shortcut, where you use the fact that the image of $e_i$ is the ith column of the matrix, but doing it by hand isn't a bad idea initially.